# Set text color to secondary color programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

How can I set the color of my text to "textColorSecondary" programmatically? I've tried the code below but it doesn't work. Does anyone know what's wrong with the code?

```
TextView tv1 = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.hello_world));
tv1.setTextColor(Color.textColorSecondary);
```

Comment: Have to searched before asking question

Comment: yes MacaronLover, i am just suggesting that search SO before asking question might be a duplicate question which have been asked before

Comment: I already did search and didn't find a duplicate hence that's why I asked it. Anyway do you know what wrong with it?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

First add `textColorSecondary` in your colors.xml

```
<color name="textColorSecondary">PutColorCodeHere</color>
```

And then set color in code :

```
tv1.setTextColor(getResource.getColor(R.color.textColorSecondary));
```

Comment: Many thanks. Do you know what wrong with my other problem by any chance?: [link to other problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688689/selected-list-view-item-background-colour-not-changing)

Comment: Let me see the link and tell you

Comment: In my previous comment, link on 'link to other problem'

Comment: I wouldn't do that. You'll end up with two resources with the same name. **app.R.color.textColorSecondary** and **android.R.attr.textColorSecondary**. You're better using the TypeValue like the answer below.

Answer (score 13):

**Edit:**

To get color from attribute use this:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Theme theme = context.getTheme();
theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.textColorSecondary, typedValue, true);
int color = typedValue.data;
```

Comment: After using that I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'textColorSecondary'`

Comment: No, I thought textColorSecondary was an attribute?

Comment: use android.R.attr.textColorSecondary

Answer (score 5):

What only really worked for me is this implementation:

```
int textColor = getTextColor(context, android.R.attr.textColorSecondary);

public int getTextColor(Context context, int attrId) {
    TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { attrId });
    int textColor = typedArray.getColor(0, 0);
    typedArray.recycle();
    return textColor;
}
```

The other solutions here returned wrong color IDs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a utility class provided by Material design library

```
@ColorInt val secondaryColor = MaterialColors.getColor(context, android.R.attr.textColorSecondary, Color.BLACK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Anton Kovalyov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4878298/anton-kovalyov) I made some extension functions from the answer for kotlin developers.

```
fun Context.getAttrColor(@AttrRes attr: Int): Int {
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedValue, true)
    return typedValue.data
}
```

You can use this function wherever you have context.